# Making a SOAP call with gowsdl

Tags: xml, web-services, go, soap

I am using `gowsdl` to consume a `SOAP` request in Go. I got `WSDL` and generated the code using that. In the auto-generated code, it generated stub and some code snippets are mentioned below.

1. I have to make a `SOAP` call and have to pass `GetAllPersons struct` as an input to the service. Please help me how do we do that? I have the request `xml` but dont know how to update that in `GetAllPersons struct`?

   ```
   persons, err := service.GetAllPersons(request)

   type GetAllPersons struct {
       XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://service.jaxws.journaldev.com getAllPersons"`
   }
   ```
2. And as per Go specification, a variable is declared using the sybtax `VariableName Type`. What is the 3rd value `xml:"http://service.jaxws.journaldev.com getAllPersons"` in above `struct`?

Comment: I fail to parse your question. Do you want to ask «which fields do I put into the `GetAllPersons` struct type which is the type representing an input request to the "getAllPersons" WS call?»?

Comment: @kostix: Have made changes to make question clear. I hope that will help.

Comment: These strings after the type are called tags (see https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) and are used typically during (un)marshalling from serialisation formats like xml.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Where did you store your password and user name? Having similar issues

Comment: @Data_Kid: Posted answer. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the code that I figured out to get things done with the code generated by `gowsdl`.

```
main(){
    basicauth := personService.BasicAuth{"",""}
    service := personService.NewPersonServiceImpl("", false, &basicauth)

    persons, err := service.GetAllPersons(&personService.GetAllPersons{})

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(persons)
    fmt.Printf("Alive?: %t\n", persons.GetAllPersonsReturn[0].Name)
    fmt.Printf("Alive?: %t\n", persons.GetAllPersonsReturn[1].Name)
    fmt.Printf("Alive?: %t\n", persons.GetAllPersonsReturn[0].Id)
    fmt.Printf("Alive?: %t\n", persons.GetAllPersonsReturn[1].Id)
    fmt.Printf("Alive?: %t\n", persons.GetAllPersonsReturn[0].Age)
    fmt.Printf("Alive?: %t\n", persons.GetAllPersonsReturn[1].Age)
    fmt.Printf(persons.GetAllPersonsReturn[0].Name)

    request := &personService.AddPerson{P: &personService.Person{Age: 24, Name: "Govinda", Id: 55555555}}
    trial, err := service.AddPerson(request)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

For the 2nd question, thanks to Volker for mentioning the answer in comments.
`These strings after the type are called tags (see golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) and are used typically during (un)marshalling from serialisation formats like xml`